# IOS - push data instead of notifications using APNS

Tags: iphone, ios4, apple-push-notifications

When I have loaded new data onto my server, I want to push a file onto my iPhone app.
Is that possible with APNS or is that only for notification of the availabillity of new data on the server(and the app must then connect to the server and download data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A push notification can only carry a very small brutto payload (256 Byte, IIRC). So no, you cannot push a file via APN (unless it's so tiny that you can cram it into the JSON body).

**Edit:** It is 256 Byte. See [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html).